# Rx.Observable.just is not a function in JSBIN & RxJS 5

Tags: rxjs5, jsbin

In JsBin, I got error "Rx.Observable.just is not a function" in Firefox & Chrome. JsBin example : http://jsbin.com/vunuta/edit?html,js,console

HTML :

```
script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js">
```

Typescript :

```
Rx.Observable.from ([1,2,3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // Work
Rx.Observable.just (99).subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // Fail
Rx.Observable.return (99).subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // Fail
```

Tx

Comment: I found why. just & return are replace by operator of
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 37):

`Rx.Observable.just()` is no longer provided in v5. Use `Rx.Observable.of()`. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 5):

**Update for rxjs v6**

Yes, use `of` instead of `just`. The import and usage of `of` changed between rxjs v5 and rxjs v6.

For rxjs v6, use `of` as in the following example code:

```
import { of } from "rxjs";

let source$ = fromPromise(getPostById(1)).pipe(
  flatMap(post => {
    return hydrateAuthor(post);
  }),
  catchError(error => of(`Caught error: ${error}`))
);
```